# Resulting in or resulted in

Tags: word-usage

I came across the following sentence and I was wondering if I can use **resulted** instead of **resulting** in the passive sense of usage as "which was resulted in"

> A massive dose of venom can cause cardiac dysfunction, **resulting**
>   in loss of consciousness and cardiac arrest and death within 5 minutes
>   of being stung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Resulting" and "resulted" are both called participles, but the present participle "resulting" is active in meaning, whereas the past participle is passive when used as a participle.

Since "result" is intransitive, it does not usually take passive forms, so the past participle "resulted" is not used as a participle. (It can be used as a verb in the perfect: "this has resulted in .. " but that is not the construction here).

Taking 'eat' as an example of a transitive verb, you can see the difference between:

> The man ran away, *eating* a sandwich.

and

> The man disappeared, *eaten* by a crocodile.

The venom, or the cardiac disfunction *results* in the loss of consciousness (active); it isn't *a result of* it (which would be the sort of passive, if *result* had a passive).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: past tense resulted would require you to be referencing a prior event where a massive dose of venom **did** cause or **could have** caused cardiac dysfunction, which obviously isn't the case as the passage is explaining the effects rather than reporting an event.